# How to fully fill the image button with images?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have these image buttons, the image for the image button are store in the
   drawable file. However, i just cannot fill the image button with the image. 
   There will still be some empty space left which make it not that beautiful.
   Is there any way to make the image button fully fill with image? Here shows
   my image button xml code.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/homepage"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"/>

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:id="@+id/buttonSignUP"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <SearchView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/viewFlipper"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:text="Search a product"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

   <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Featured promotion"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

   <ViewFlipper
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/view_flipper"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/banner5" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/banner6" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/banner7" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/banner8" />
    </RelativeLayout>
   </ViewFlipper>

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Categories"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">

   <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:src="@drawable/fashion"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton3" />

   <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:src="@drawable/book"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">

   <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:src="@drawable/sport"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

   <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:src="@drawable/healthcare"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">

    <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:src="@drawable/computer"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageButton2" />

   <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:src="@drawable/phone"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">

   <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
    android:src="@drawable/stationary"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

   <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
    android:src="@drawable/others"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageButton6"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageButton6"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

OR

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

For eg.

```
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/fashion"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use the `android:scaleType` attribute to fill the `ImageButton`. I generally use `fitXY` or `fitCenter` to cover the `ImageButton` with the image. To remove gray background, use `android:background="@null"`. For example -

```
<ImageButton
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
android:src="@drawable/book"
android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton5"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:background="@null" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add ScaleType

   ```
   android:scaleType="fitXY"
   ```
2. and Background as null to remove grey background

   ```
   android:background="@null"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

you can use android:scaleType="fitXY"